# How to access list items within ul that get added via a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am basically working on a responsive navigation bar where if the current window width doesn't accommodate the number of items, last item of the list will get appended to another un-ordered list.

My problem is I need to target menu items within the hidden list which is empty when the width of the window is 100%. I could access the un-ordered list for visible list but not for the hidden list as per below jQuery. I understand that I am trying to access items that doesn't exist yet, but there must be a way.

**Snippet:**

```js
 var $vlinks = $('#hrmenu .visible-links');
 var $hlinks = $('#hrmenu .hidden-links');
 availableSpace = $vlinks.width() - 30;
 var
 break = [];
 areaAvail += w + 20;
 break.push(areaAvail);
 visibleItems = $vlinks.children().length;
 requiredSpace =
   break [visibleItems - 1];


 if (requiredSpace > availableSpace) {
   $vlinks.children().last().prependTo($hlinks);
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {

   //Visible list            
   $('#shuffle-btn > li > a').click(function(event) {
     $item = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li');
     console.log($item.index());
   });

   //Hidden list list             
   $('#hidshuffle-btn > li > a').click(function(event) {
     $item = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li');
     console.log($item.index());
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="hrmenu" class="prdct-hrmenu">

  <ul id="shuffle-btn" class="visible-links">
    <li><a href="#">item-1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Item-1-a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item-2</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Item-1-a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item-3</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Item-3-a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item-4</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Item-4-a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="hidshuffle-btn" class="hidden-links">
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the elements in the hidden list are not available during DOM ready, you need to define a click handler that can delegate to these elements when they are available. You can use JQuery's `on` function for this like below.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   //Hidden list list             
   $('#hidshuffle-btn').on('click', ' li > a', function(event){
        var $item = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li');
        console.log($item.index());
   });

 });
```

Here's a sample [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbLAWy?editors=1010) in action :)

Comment: I left out a comma in my original answer. I just edited my answer and also added a sample pen. Try it out. It should work

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added elements, you just need to change your line from:

```
$('#shuffle-btn > li > a').click(function(event) {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '#shuffle-btn > li > a', function(event) {
```

Similarly for the hidden list:

```
$('#hidshuffle-btn > li > a').click(function(event) {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '#hidshuffle-btn > li > a', function(event) {
```

**@Arkantos's answer is more correct in terms of performance.

Comment: It's preferred to register the event handler on the nearest static container like `hidshuffle-btn` rather than on the document itself. That way event delegation doesn't have to start at the root of the document

Comment: You are correct @Arkantos. Will delete my answer. Yours is more accurate.